# Why is mongoDB not displaying all results

Tags: mongodb

this might seem quite simple but does anyone know why mongoDB is only returning the first 20 results despite importing 800 from a CSV file?

[image: Import]

[image: 20th result]
Thanks

Comment: See [DBQuery.shellBatchSize](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-mongo-shell/#change-the-mongo-shell-batch-size)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mongo shell is not intended to be a production client, it is an administrative and test tool.

When you run a query, the mongo shell returns and displays the first batch of results.  You will need to either request an additional batch (i.e. Type "it" for more), use a method like `toArray` to exhaust the cursor, or save the cursor to a variable so you can iterate it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, ill keep it in mind!